# How to access a dictionary element in django template?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I have a dictionary named `income` in a django template, I also have a list named `factors` in my template and I want something like this :

```
{% for factor in factors%}
<div> {{ income[factor.id] }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

but {{ income[factor.id] }} is wrong, how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a template tag like so:

```
@register.filter
def get_value(d, key):
    return d.get(key)
```

and use it like so:

```
{{ income|get_value:factor.id }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: as pointed out by @kbnk, I was mistaken and this does not work.

If you don't want to create a filter, you can try the following:

```
{% for factor in factors %}
    {% with factor_id=factor.id %}
        <div> {{ income.factor_id] }} </div>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, because you can do a dictionary-type lookout in django templates. Checkout the django template docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Comment: This won't work, as the template will take the literal string `'factor_id'` as the dictionary key, not the value of the `factor_id` variable.

Comment: @kbnk : can I do anything to fix this and use this method ? I don't want to create a filter for this

Comment: @Navid777 You can solve it by refactoring `income` and `factors` in some way in your view code, but otherwise you need a template filter.